# Why is this bash script always evaluating false

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying out my first bash script just to run through some files through a another script and check the answers.

```
for i in tests/*;
do
  if [ "${i: -2}" != ".a" ] ; then
    A=`cat "$i" | python3 blah.py`
    B=`cat "$i.a"`
    if (("$A" == "$B")); then
      printf "Passed $i\n\n"
    else
      echo "Failed $i:"
      echo "Calculated Answer: $A"
      printf "   Correct Answer: $B\n\n"
    fi
  fi
done
```

And it seems no matter how I mess around with this script I get outputs like:

```
Failed tests/23:
Calculated Answer: 33334
   Correct Answer: 33334
```

Where my calculated answer will be the same as the given answer, but the script will say I failed.

Comment: There may be some non-printing characters in there.  Try piping your output through `hexdump` or similar to see if that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, so maybe its your version of bash, be careful about that. I'm on OSX:

```
bash --version
> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
A="1"
B="1"
if (("$A" == "$B")); then
    printf "Passed $i\n\n"
else
    echo "Failed $i:"
    echo "Calculated Answer: $A"
    printf "   Correct Answer: $B\n\n"
fi
> Passed
A="1"
B="2"
if (("$A" == "$B")); then
    printf "Passed $i\n\n"
else
    echo "Failed $i:"
    echo "Calculated Answer: $A"
    printf "   Correct Answer: $B\n\n"
fi
> Failed :
>    Calculated Answer: 1
>    Correct Answer: 2
```

One thing that stood out was the parans. I don't typically use () for if's, just [ ] or [[ ]] (spaces in the statement matter). I don't know when it matters, if I just use [] because maybe its backward compatible with old /bin/sh environments. But try replacing them. Also, printf? I honestly didn't know you could use it, I always used echo. : ) Oh well, it works:

```
if [[ "$A" == "$B" ]]; then
    printf "Passed $i\n\n"
else
    echo "Failed $i:"
    echo "Calculated Answer: $A"
    printf "   Correct Answer: $B\n\n"
fi
```

Try the above, and let us know what version of bash/sh/other interpreter you're using.

Comment: `printf` is definitely preferred over `echo` because it is well-defined and standardized.  The round parentheses are used exclusively for arithmetic evaluation; `[` is the general portable `test` while `[[` is a Bash extension.